# Existence of a cone neighbourhood in an open disc with a point in the border

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I started reading C. P. Rourke and B. J. Sanderson’s “Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology” which is recommended by D. Rolfsen in “Knots and Links”, they provide the following definition:

1.1 A subset $P \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a *polyhedron* if each point $a\in P$ has a cone neighbourhood $N=aL$ in $P$, where $L$ is compact.

Before this we only get a definition of cone as follows:

For $a\in \mathbb{R}^n, B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\notin B$, their *join* $aB=\{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b:b\in B, \lambda \in[0,1]\}$ is called a *cone* with vertex $a$ and base $B$ if each point in $aB$ is expressed **uniquely** as $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $b\in B$ as before, except for $a$ of course.

I have a couple issues with this definition, for instance:

- By *cone neighbourhood in P* do they mean a cone $aL$ such that $aL\subset P$ is true and **also** there is an open subset $O\subset P$ —open in the subspace topology (?)— such that $a\in O\subset aL$?

My confusion arose after this example (the second one), to be found in the next page of the book:

[image: an open disk with a tail - a closed line segment outside the disk with one endpoint, a, on the boundary]

I get that the given space is not by any means a polyhedron, but the author says that it is not because there is no cone neighbourhood, but because the one that exists has a non-compact base, but I’ve come to feel pretty sure that there isn’t one at all, since the only two reasonable candidates for the base $L$ would be an open chord or an interior circumference tangent to the disk’s boundary precisely at $a$ (excluding $a$ so that it is not in $L$); but both of these attempts leave “gaps” which make it impossible to fit a basic open of $P$ containing $a$ inside of them.

[image: Illustration of my previous argument]

My question is: am I right about this little correction? Knowing that would really help me to move on confidently, since this is already one of the very first definitions of the book.

P.s. I omitted the rest of the tail in my previous reasoning because it is not relevant, and the true pathology of the example is a consequence of the point in the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If the authors meant anything else by "cone neighborhood" than a neighborhood of $a$ that is also a cone, they surely would have given a definition for the phrase. You will have to check whether they did, as I do not have access to a copy. You might try looking up the phrase in the index and checking the early references. If they didn't give such a definition, then the interpretation you gave must be correct.

In that case, you are correct that by the definitions given - particularly the "uniqueness" requirement - $a$ does not have any neighborhood in $X$ that is a cone. To see that this is true in general, let $D$ be the open disk in $X$. Any neighborhood of $a$ (to be clear, I mean any set containing an open set containing $a$) must have the intersection of an open disk $U$ centered on $a$ with $D$ as a subset. Note that a portion of the boundary of $D$ in the plane lies inside $U$, and $U \cap \overline D$ is convex.

Any ray eminating from $a$ and passing through a point of $\overline D$ must also contain points of $U$, So some initial segment of that ray must lie in $U\cap D$. If the neighborhood is a cone $aL$, then there has to be a unique point $l \in L$ lying on the ray. If $d \in \partial D\cap U, d\ne a$, then $l$ lies on the segment $ad$ but cannot be $d$ since $d$ itself is not in $X$. Thus there are interior points of $dl$ lying inside $U\cap D \subset U\cap X$ but are not in the cone $aL$, contradicting that $aL$ is a neighborhood.

---

It is possible the authors were thinking of a *closed* disk when they said $a$ has a cone neighborhood that is not compact. In that case $X$ itself would be a cone neighborhood of $a$ with base $L$ consisting of the end of the tail and the boundary of the disk with $a$ removed, because $a$ cannot be in $L$. Since $a$ is removed, $L$ is not closed, and therefore not compact.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that is the first mention of the term in the book, but considering a couple other examples they give, the meaning is most likely what we’re thinking of. The only thing I would point in your answer is that even in the case where the disc was supposed to be closed, they do say that $X-a$ is a polyhedron, which wouldn’t be true in that case (because of the other points in the boundary), so maybe they really just should have written that $a$ has no cone neighbourhood at all. But your answer did give me the solid confirmation I needed to proceed, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> By *cone neighbourhood in P* do they mean a cone $aL$ such that $aL\subset P$ is true and **also** there is an open subset $O\subset P$ such that $a\in O\subset aL$?

Yes, a cone neighborhood of $a \in P$ is a neighborhood of $a$ in $P$ which has the form $aL \subset P$ for some $L \subset P \setminus \{a\}$. A cone neighborhood in general is not an open neighborhood. If $L$ is required to be compact, then $aL$ is a compact neighborhood of $a$ (which *may* nevertheless be open in $P$).

**Therefore polyhedra are locally compact subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$.**

Thus the space $X$ in the second example is not a polyhedron because $a$ does not have *any* compact neighborhood in $X$. The point $a$ has a neighborhood which is a join: Let $D$ denote the open disk and $e$ the endpoint of the tail. Taking $L = D \cup \{e\}$ we get $aL = X$.

However, $a$ does not have a cone neighbourhood as shown in Paul Sinclair's answer, and this contradicts the claim of the authors. Taking the closed disk instead of the open disk would solve *this* issue, but in that case $X' = X \setminus \{a\}$ is not a polyhedron. In fact, no boundary point of $X'$ has a cone neighborhood with a compact base.

I think the best variation of the second example is to replace the open disk $D$ by an open triangle $T$ with a tail at one of its vertices $a$. Then one can take $L = G \cap T$, where $G$ is a line between $a$ and the edge of $T$ not containing $a$.

Comment: Thank you, but in that case taking $L$ as you say, while I agree it would now be a neighbourhood of $a$, and it would be presented in the form of a *join*, it is not a cone because of the **uniqueness** condition, so I don't think it qualifies as a cone neighbourhood since it is not a cone.

Comment: @JuanFelipeSalamancaLozano You are right, I didn't read properly and ignored the uniqueness condition for a cone. See my update.